# What are edit suggestions?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

Recently I receive edit suggestions (see the marked "5" in the screenshot) in my menu bar.[image]
As y'all can see I've a mere 1,144 rep and won't be able to edit anything. If I click the marked 5, I get an overview of what has been edited by users with lower rep, but I can't approve or dismiss anything. Probably that's just ok. But why do I receive these suggestions?

Found a similar question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77567/receiving-edit-suggestions-review-section-and-doesnt-work), though the fella has way more rep than I have and should have access to moderator tools, so my situation is a little different.

Comment: my bug fixed now ... missing setting

Comment: thanks waffles ! never experienced the bug before. just today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggested edits are edits made by users who do not have enough rep (2k) to directly edit. Instead they can suggest an edit which is then queued for peer review by users who have 2k rep or more i.e. they can be approved or rejected.

I'm pretty sure you should not be able to see them in practice. I can also see suggested edits on meta although I do not have enough rep to approve\reject. It's quite irritating to be honest.

The feature is new and they are ironing out some usability kinks. It is going through a teething phase at the moment.